# What is the use of python-dotenv?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-dotenv

Need an example and please explain me the purpose of python-dotenv.

I am kind of confused with the documentation.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

From the [Github page](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv):

> Reads the key,value pair from .env and adds them to environment variable. It is great of managing app settings during development and in production using 12-factor principles.

Assuming you have created the `.env` file along-side your settings module.

```
.
├── .env
└── settings.py
```

Add the following code to your `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv

dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
```

`.env` is a simple text file with each environment variable listed one per line, in the format of KEY="Value". The lines starting with # are ignored.

```
SOME_VAR=someval
# I am a comment and that is OK
FOO="BAR"
```

Comment: Wish i found the same on github please elobarate

Comment: just want to add, to have to be careful if key/value pair looks like `GIRLFRIEND=None` as `print` shows `None` so in this case you have to check for `type` of the variable to distinguish.

Comment: Can anyone explain the difference / pros and cons of dotenv vs autoenv?

Comment: you need to `import os` to get `os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")`

Comment: Just wanna share. I am on Mac OS. Used `VAR1=var1`, `VAR2="var2"`, `VAR3=None` and all result as string. The last one prints out `None` as typelogic mention but it is string-typed `None`.

Comment: @user9074332 the `DATABASE_PASSWORD` is set in the .env file along with SOME_VAR and FOO. It could be DATABASE_PASSWORD="InsecurePassword"

Comment: Does doetenv know where the file is stored even if you move it afterwards? I moved my .env file to a different location after reading from it succesfully, and for some reason my Python script is able to read from it.

Comment: is the recommendation to have as many env files as there are app environments, e.g. `.env-dev`, `.env-prod`, etc or just different 'sections' within the single file? Also, what if I want some of the config items to be version-controlled in git without the passwords? Is it recommended then to create separate `.env.password` files or something to that effect?

Comment: @user9074332 The `.env` file convention includes a leading `.` which makes it hidden on mac & linux systems. You would also add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file so it can't be committed to version control. If it is only local and gitignored then it is fine to have a password in it. It should only be called `.env` not many of them. If you want to use dotenv in CI/CD on different environments then something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581164/1335793 can work but depends on your deployment platform and process.

Comment: `in production using 12-factor principles` refers to the principle https://12factor.net/config of storing config in env vars. Storing them in a local gitignored `.env` file is just an implicit helper to export env vars, so you don't forget to export or to run a shell script. When deploying to prod you abandon the `.env` file. The `load_dotenv()` and the `os.environ.get` calls are independent; `dotenv` works for local development and you use some other mechanism such as your CI/CD system's env vars secrets manager in prod, either way the `os.environ.get` part always works.

Comment: @Tartaglia as it is specified in the documentation of the `load_dotenv` method, it first searches for a file in the current directory named .env and if not found moves to a parent directory so if you moved it to a parent directory it should still get detected. So, dotenv does not keep track of where the files are.

Comment: is the env variable scope limited to a particular virtual environment if it is activated? or the same user will be able to access it out of it?

Answer (score 90):

In addition to [@Will's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41547163/2745495), the python-dotenv module comes with a `find_dotenv()` that will try to find the .env file.

```
# settings.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
```

Comment: load_dotenv() is enough if you have the `.env` file in the current directory

Answer (score 20):

You could set the env variables like this:

```
 export PRIVATE_KEY=0X32323
```

and then read it with `os` module.

```
import os

private_key=os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
```

But this way, environment variable works only for the duration that shell is live. If you close the shell and restart it, you have to set environmental variable again. `python-dotenv` prevents us from doing this repetitive work.For this create `.env` file and add variables in this format

```
 PRIVATE_KEY=fb6b05d6e75a93e30e22334443379292ccd29f5d815ad93a86ee23e749227
```

then in the file u want to access anv variables

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv 

#default directory for .env file is the current directory
#if you set .env in different directory, put the directory address load_dotenv("directory_of_.env)
load_dotenv()
```

`load_dotenv()` will set the environment variables from `.env` and we access with `os` module

```
   private_key=os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding to [@cannin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625082/2745495), if you want to specify the which file you want to find:

```
from dotenv import find_dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_file = find_dotenv(".env.dev")
load_dotenv(env_file)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're starting your app from a shell such as bash or zsh, then the point of .env management utilities like (npm) dotenv or python-dotenv becomes moot.

Here's an example of how to manage .env with bash that simply, directly, and safely addresses configuration as recommended by the 12-Factor App. It also requires no additional dependencies.

Given a project hosted under `~/projects/foobar/`, create an environment file in a safe location outside your project's space (e.g. `~/.envs/foobar/dev`). Its content may look something like this:

```
set -a

PROJECT=foobar
DB_NAME=foobar_dev
DB_PASSWORD=5ecret
CACHE_ENABLED=
DEBUG=yes
LOG=/tmp/foobar.log
...

set +a
```

Then create a symlink to that file from your project's space:

```
$ ln -s ~/.envs/foobar/dev ~/projects/foobar/.env
```

The project now has a `.env` file symlinking to the actual file. When you source the symlink, all variables between `set -a` and `set +a` are exported to the environment.

```
$ source ~/projects/foobar/.env
```

And voila! If you run python from the same shell instance you sourced the environment file, you can retrieve the latter and update your config with it:

```
import os
config.update(os.environ)
```

The point of making `.env` a symlink to `~/.envs/foobar/dev` is an added precaution to listing it in .gititgnore. If for whatever reasons the file were to be checked into version control, its contents would just show that it's a link to another file.

Comment: Interesting edge case: I was using Prefect to orchestrate python code, and the default upload behavior is to follow symlinks and upload the file (to local storage or S3 for example.) **Therefore, protecting a local file from a repo by symlinking can fail**, where using an `env` variable to referece a file location will be OK.

Comment: @Merlin My answer presumes common knowledge that .env is a private, user specific file and thus should be included in .gitignore. No one wants to deal with teammates's .env in the repo, symlinks or not. That's why I say that making it a symlink is an *added precaution to listing it in .gitignore*. It's not a replacement. But people can forget. If I accidentally check it in, I'd prefer to have the added likelihood that it's checked in as a symlink, even if that's not an absolute certainty (with Prefect and such).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to elaborate on **1)** what `load_dotenv` actually does under the hood, and **2)** the relationship between the `os.environ` and the OS's environment variables.

As the accepted answer describes, we can store some keys & values in the `.env` file and load it using the `load_dotenv`; then the `os.environ` contains the key-value pairs in the `.env` file.

Does this mean invoking `load_dotenv` added an OS environment variable? - No.

Actually, what `load_dotenv` does is quite the same as `os.environ['key'] = 'value'`; see the [source code](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/blob/d6c0b9638349a7dd605d60ee555ff60421c1a594/src/dotenv/main.py#L99).

*But,* `os.environ['key'] = 'value'` does *not* add this key&value as an OS environment variable; They are only valid while the Python script is running.

In other words, `os.environ` contains not only the OS environment variables but also one-time variables like these.