# Access env variables in node js app when using gitlab ci cd pipeline

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, pm2

I am using gitlab ci cd pipe line to deploy my application to ubuntu server. I have different .env file for local and for dev env and its not a part of git repo (included in gitignore) how to get env variables in my app when deployed to ubuntu server

my gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
     - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
      - npm install
      - sudo pm2 delete lknodeapi || true
      - sudo pm2 start server.js --name lknodeapi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a .env file in gitlab ci during deployment stage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540316/how-do-i-add-a-env-file-in-gitlab-ci-during-deployment-stage)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this -[Create Variables Gitlab](https://clouddocs.f5.com/training/community/nginx/html/class2/module1/lab/lab2.html).You can create your environment variables in the ui and then change your `gitlab-ci.yml` like below

```
stages:
     - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
      - echo "NGINX_REPO_KEY"=$NGINX_REPO_KEY >> ".env"
      - npm install
      - sudo pm2 delete lknodeapi || true
      - sudo pm2 start server.js --name lknodeapi
```

This will create a .env file in root folder and put your variables in it.

Comment: Hi, I really need help with pm2. So i did everything as every tutorial suggests. my pm2 status is active and online, i also did the pm2 startup part but still my app is not working. When i stop pm2 and run `node index.js` my app works. Why is pm2 not working?

Comment: pls check for logs ,sudo pm2 logs @kd12345

Comment: @Shubh i am not getting any errors, PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:47:04: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:47:04: PM2 log: Time                 : Wed Jan 27 2021 06:47:04 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:47:04: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 4.5.1
PM2        | 2021-01-27T06:47:04: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 12.20.1

Comment: can't say anything about it then

Comment: My data from my database is not getting loaded for some reason, its working with when i start the app with node but not with pm2

Comment: Please post a separate question with all the details and tag me @kd12345

Comment: ok thank you, what files should i include in my question default.conf and nginx.conf?