# Discord bot commands not working (Python)

Tags: python, discord

I am currently using python to code my first discord bot. While trying to write a command, I saw that I was unable to do this. This code:

```
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = 'NzQxMjA2OTQzMDc4ODA5NjEy.Xy0Mwg.Shkr9hHvkn-y4l5ye1yTHYM3rQo'
client = discord.Client()
    
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!')

pp = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

messages = ["hello", "hi", "how are you?"]
@pp.command(name = "swear")
async def swear(ctx):
    await ctx.send(rand.choice(messages))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

is not outputting anything in the discord application when I type !swear. The bot is online, and working normally for other codes such as:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!')
```

Here is the full code:

```
import discord
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = (##my token spelled out)
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('im in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
 
    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hi there!')
        
    elif message.content.startswith("Is Ethan's mum gay?"):
        await message.channel.send("Yep, 100%!")
    
    elif message.content.startswith("What are you doing?"):
        await message.channel.send(f"Step {message.author}")
        
    elif 'happy birthday' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Happy Birthday! ')
        
    
    
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!')

pp = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

messages = ["hello", "hi", "how are you?"]
@pp.command(name = "swear")
async def swear(ctx):
    await ctx.send(rand.choice(messages))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix my problem?

Comment: By pasting your token here, you have given everyone the password for your bot. Go refresh it right now! (Ps the token is supposed to go in a separate file.)

Comment: Do you know how to put it into a seperate file? I'm not sure what you are talking about...

Comment: Pretty sure that’s what dotenv is for https://stackoverflow.com/a/41547163/6083675. But you need to prioritize resetting your token.

Comment: as for me `Client()` and `Bot()` are two different methods to create bot - so you create two bots at the same time - and you can't use them together because you would need `client.run(TOKEN)` and `pp.run(TOKEN)` to run both at the same time. You should rather use only `Bot()` and `@pp.event` instead of `@client.event`

Answer (score 1):

`Client()` and `Bot()` are two methods to create bot and using both at the same time is wrong.

Using `Client()` and `Bot()` you create two bots but they would need `client.run(TOKEN)` and `pp.run(TOKEN)` to run together - but it makes problem to start them at the same time and it can make conflict which one should get user message.

`Bot()` is extended version of `Client()` so you need only `Bot()` and use

- `@pp.event` instead of `@client.event`
- `pp.run(TOKEN)` instead of `client.run(TOKEN)`
- `pp.user` instead of `client.user`

---

**EDIT:**

And you have to define `pp` before all functions. Like this

```
import random
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

pp = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@pp.event
async def on_ready():
    print('im in as {}'.format(pp.user))

@pp.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == pp.user:
        return
 
    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hi there!')
        
    elif message.content.startswith("Is Ethan's mum gay?"):
        await message.channel.send("Yep, 100%!")
    
    elif message.content.startswith("What are you doing?"):
        await message.channel.send(f"Step {message.author}")
        
    elif 'happy birthday' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Happy Birthday! ')
    
@pp.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!')

messages = ["hello", "hi", "how are you?"]

@pp.command(name = "swear")
async def swear(ctx):
    await ctx.send(rand.choice(messages))

pp.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: When I use pp.event, the code responds with ```NameError: name 'pp' is not defined``` .

Comment: you have to define `pp = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` before all `@pp.even` - it is so obious that I didn't mentioned it .