# I keep getting 'None' when getting enviroment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, discord.py

I'm trying to keep my token in an enviroment variable, so I created the file .env, and I stored the TOKEN there:

```
TOKEN=XXX
```

When I run my .py file, I can't get the enviroment variable TOKEN, it keeps printing 'None'.

```
import os
    
token = os.environ.get("TOKEN")
print(token)
```

Comment: Please check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41547163/5186565

Comment: seems you must `load_dotenv` first.

Comment: Please re-generate your token as it can be seen in the edit history.

Comment: Tokens are private and should **never** be shared with other people. It's like a password connected to you. Go to the developer site of Discord and regenerate a new token, or else people will be able to use it to make requests with your account.

Comment: @Dominik I changed some characters, don't worry

Comment: @s0urce No, you can't just change some characters. You have to go to Discord and regenerate a completely new token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is use a dotenv variable directly using os.environ.
In order to use variables from .env, you need the dotenv library.
Install dotenv library:

```
pip install dotenv
```

Then import dotenv like this.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()  # this will load variables from .env.
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the error, I had to load the enviroment variable

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried the answers mentioned by @Shadab and you're still getting `None` while printing the values from env.

> Maybe you didn't created the .env file in the correct file directory.

We meed to create the `.env` file within project scope, not inside any folders.