# Unable to locate credentials in boto3 AWS

Tags: python, amazon-s3, visual-studio-code, boto3, botocore

I'm trying to view S3 bucket list through a python scripts using boto3. Credential file and config file is available in the C:\Users\user1.aws location. Secret access and access key available there for user "vscode". But unable to run the script which return exception message as

```
"botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials".
```

Code sample follows,

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():     
    print(bucket.name)
```

Do I need to specify user mentioned above ("vscode") ?

Copied the credential and config file to folder of python script is running. But same exception occurs.

Comment: You should checkout the python-dotenv package. You can store the secrets in a `.env` file at your root and retrieve these using the package. I think that should solve the problem. You can also check this [What is the use of python-dotenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546883/what-is-the-use-of-python-dotenv) for more information.

Comment: You should use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command to store the credentials in the standard credentials location. Then, boto3 will automatically retrieve those credentials.

Comment: Actually I change the [vscode] to [default] in the credentials file of C:\Users\user1\.aws location. Now no exceptions. I don't clear what's happening there @anosha_rehan

Answer (score 4):

When I got this error, I replaced `resource` with `client` and also added the secrets during initialization:

```
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=settings.AWS_REGION, aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                          aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Answer (score -5):

You can try with `boto3.client('s3')` instead of `boto3.resource('s3')`