# Python script connecting to oracle DB with env variables

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm practicing with Python, environment variables and oracle database.

I want to create a python script who's :

- connecting to an oracle db, credentials not showing up (located in an env variable)
- execute a query on the database
- transform this query result into an excel file (xlsx)
- create the excel file on a specific harddrive

## Here's my current script :

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect( -> ***should I insert here the env variable name file ?***)

df_ora = pd.read_sql('''select * from example_db''', conn)

df_ora = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)

df_ora.to_csv(os.environ["user"] + "\\Desktop" + "file_name" +".csv")
```

To be honest i'm lost with cx_Oracle and pandas, can't figure what to set for this kind of script.
Tried to learn on multiple videos, libraries informations and from here but everytime I find a documentation it seems not accurate for my needs.
A bit of help and explaination would help me grow on about scripting for sure.
Best regards,

Comment: cx_Oracle is the old python driver, the oracledb driver is much more developer-friendly... python -m pip install oracledb

Answer (score 0):

You're doing pretty good so far, although some parts aren't clear from your question.

I'm assuming that you're setting environment variables like this? (on windows using cmd.exe)

```
set username=romsnp
set password=SecretPassword123!
```

Then you call the python script:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

username = os.environ.get('username')
password = os.environ.get('password')

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn="yourserver.com/ServiceName")

df_ora = pd.read_sql('''select * from example_db''', conn)

# the previous line already creates a dataframe, so you don't need to do it again

df_ora.to_csv("file_name.csv")
```

For testing, I would try starting out just exporting the file to the same directory you're running the script in. Depending on your OS, figuring out the correct filesystem path can be a confusing issue.

Another thing that might help - when trying to figure out Python scripting issues, it can help a lot to run it interactively. The easiest way is to use [the python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) by just calling `python` from the command line, then enter your script one line at a time to make sure each command works as expected.

For example, you could try running `pd.read_sql('''select * from example_db''', conn)` by itself to make sure your query and connection is working. Or you could run `print(os.environ["user"] + "\\Desktop" + "file_name" +".csv")` to verify what your filepath will look like before trying to write to it.

Using interactive notebooks like Jupyter is also a popular way to do this kind of experimentation without the frustration of trying to debug a shell script.

Edit: if the environment variables are confusing or not working, another common way to hide your credentials is using [dotenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546883/what-is-the-use-of-python-dotenv)

Create a file in the same directory as the script named `.env`:

```
username=romsnp
password=SecretPassword123!
host=yourserver.com/ServiceName
```

Then you can load it into your Python environment:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# loads the credentials from the file into environment
load_dotenv() 

# loads the credentials from environment into variables
username = os.environ.get('username')
password = os.environ.get('password')
host = os.environ.get('host')

# use the variable names; the secrets from the .env file are never displayed
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=host)

...continued...
```

Comment: Thank you so much kfinity for your support. I am on windows 11 23H2, using python 3.11.
Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I want the parenthesis part to not be shown in this script : 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn="yourserver.com/ServiceName")
The user will always be the same to connect to DB to export sql query into xlsx data for daily reports.
Right now my script work as export into a server folder, but the database and credentials are visible and the exporting is a csv.
Debugging by line is very usefull also, thanks !

Comment: I edited to make it more clear how to use Windows environment variables, but also `dotenv`. In both examples the credentials are not stored in the script at all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. I tested but seems not working : 
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

The user, password and hostname are correct when I log on into sql developer oracle DB.
My .env file looks like you suggested above (using a username and password allowed to access the DB, but it's not a windows account located on my computer).
The host line of .env looks like :  IP adress:port/db name, example : 198.168.10.150:1521/ORACLE_DB

Not sure what I am missing here ? The account i'm using to access DB is not local by the way.
Regards

Comment: Ok - it works when you hardcode the password in the file, but not with a .env file? You might try print()ing the username/password before using them. If your password has special characters in it, you might need to put the password in single/double quotes, or maybe even escape the special characters with a backslash.

Comment: Yes exactly. When I print it, it says 'name "username" is not defined'. There is no special characters in the username or password. 
Here is my current "loading credentials" part of the script :

load_dotenv()
username = os.environ.get('username')
password = os.environ.get('password')
host = os.environ.get('host')

#sql connection
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=host)
And in the .env I've set :
user=username 
password=password
dsn=dsn